# Installing spring boot 4 on eclipse marketplace bug

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, eclipse, maven

When i try to install spring boot 4 from the eclipse enterprise marketplace it gives me this error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springframework.boot.ide.main.feature,4.16.0.202209151144.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile4943392527699778307.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile4943392527699778307.jar
Problems downloading artifact: binary,org.springframework.boot.ide.main.feature_root,4.16.0.202209151144.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile6217771959087543644.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile6217771959087543644.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.live,4.16.0.202209151144.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile7582271787004894753.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile7582271787004894753.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot,4.16.0.202209151144.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile17455786453498510958.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile17455786453498510958.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash,4.16.0.202209151144.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile1007839680012004648.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile1007839680012004648.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash.cf,4.16.0.202209151144.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile9177732891863162585.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile9177732891863162585.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash.docker,4.16.0.202209151144.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile10670787780309912168.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile10670787780309912168.jar
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash.feature,4.16.0.202209151144.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile674815030375978216.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile674815030375978216.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.launch,4.16.0.202209151144.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile2565548804631224580.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile2565548804631224580.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.refactoring,4.16.0.202209151144.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5678240629295744215.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5678240629295744215.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.restart,4.16.0.202209151144.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile8032861415938568316.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile8032861415938568316.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.templates,4.16.0.202209151144.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile2435013977189726989.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile2435013977189726989.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.validation,4.16.0.202209151144.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile14233253980832995429.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile14233253980832995429.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.wizard,4.16.0.202209151144.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile18322017414743641069.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile18322017414743641069.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.buildship30,4.16.0.202209151144.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile12754653215161193585.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile12754653215161193585.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.docker.client,4.16.0.202209151144.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile15021084922616637580.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile15021084922616637580.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.imports,4.16.0.202209151144.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile3905959110866512809.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile3905959110866512809.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.maven.pom,4.16.0.202209151144.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile9535522334882972957.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile9535522334882972957.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.xml.namespaces,4.16.0.202209151144.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile12146099126646089231.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile12146099126646089231.jar
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.xml.namespaces.feature,4.16.0.202209151144.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile17322411091426765788.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile17322411091426765788.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.cloudfoundry.client.v2,4.16.0.202209151144.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile2325110498129798983.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\otoja\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile2325110498129798983.jar
```

How do i fix this error?

Comment: Which Eclipse version? Please show the error log message starting with `!SESSION`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, no need of doing that thing,

you can use [spring tool suite](https://spring.io/tools) similar to your IDE

or

create a project using [this spring initializer](https://start.spring.io/) link, add all the dependencies and download the project,

after that open the project in eclipse IDE as a Maven project and wait for a while till the project import all jars and built it (this process is automatic, the ide will handle it), then hopefully your program will work as a Maven project.

ping me if you need any other help.

Comment: Hi, I tried using the spring initializer, but when I try to import it into my eclipse enterprise workspace, I get an error that states no projects are found to import in the archive file.

Comment: go to    File >> Open Projects from File system... >>  Directory... >> (select your project folder) >> Finish,  wait for a while it built the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `STS(Spring Tool Suite)` while using eclipse. 
STS Link [here](https://spring.io/tools)